# Intersentence space after parenthesis with microtype spacing=true

Tags: microtype

I've noticed that spaces after a parenthesis preceded by a full stop (*i.e.* spaces after a sentence fully enclosed in parentheses) are treated as normal spaces, not intersentence spaces, when `spacing=true`.

For example, in the following (with `spacing=false`) the first line is different to the second line, indicating a true intersentence space is used in the first.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spacing=false]{microtype}
%\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}

\begin{document}
One sentence. (Some text.) New sentence.

One sentence. (Some text.)\ New sentence.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whereas when `spacing=true`, the two sentences are identical, suggesting that the intersentence space is not noticed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spacing=true]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}

\begin{document}
One sentence. (Some text.) New sentence.

One sentence. (Some text.)\ New sentence.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I appreciate `spacing=true` is 'experimental', but is there any way to turn on intersentence spacing for this context?

Comment: `One sentence.\ (Some text.) New sentence.` comes out wrong as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `spacing` option uses the same model with the space factor codes as standard TeX.